# Function call of other contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

Can someone, please, explain, how this works:

I have contract `MigrationAgent` which has `migrateFrom()` function (not implemented). And I have `NewContract` is `MigrationAgent` which implements `migrateFrom()`. I deployed that contract, have its address `0x*****`.

To call this function from other contract, as I see in example, I have to do this: `MigrationAgent(0x*****).migrateFrom();`

Why is this? I can't understand logic of this syntax. Why can't I write `0x*****.migrateFrom()` and what if I write `MigrationAgent(0x*****).migrateFrom()` when `0x*****` is not `MigrationAgent`?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this? I can't understand logic of this syntax. Why can't I
>   write 0x*****.migrateFrom()

0x***** is just an address, you have to write

`MigrationAgent(0x*****).migrateFrom()`;

in order to instantiate a MigrationAgent contract. Once you have done so you can call its defined functions.

> and what if I write MigrationAgent(0x*****).migrateFrom() when 0x*****
>   is not MigrationAgent?

The execution would fail, unless said contract did have the function signature defined. In that case, it would do whatever the function defined on that contract does, which can be dangerous.
That's why you should avoid calling functions on other contracts, specially if you don't know what those contracts are.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer  
So when I write `ContractName(address)` it means smth like type casting, and fails if it's not possible. And if I use `new` do I deploy new contract to the blockchain?

Comment: If you do MigrationAgent m = MigrationAgent(0X...); you are instantiating an existing contract deployed to that address.
On the other hand, if you do MigrationAgent m = new MigrationAgent(constructor_param_1,constructor_param_2,constructor_param_etc); you are creating a new contract and deploying it.